# Godaddy CNAME record does not work with heroku DNS target

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

I have bought the following domain www.rodrigoloza.com from GoDaddy. I have a Django application deployed in heroku https://rodrigo-blog-123456.herokuapp.com/ 
I wanted to add my www domain to my heroku app, so I edited the CNAME of my DNS and added the following information.

Type: CNAME

Name: www

Value: rodrigoloza.com.herokudns.com

TTL: 1 Hour

When I check `heroku domains -a app_name` I get that the domain name has been set to the DNS target www.rodrigoloza.com.herokudns.com but when I click on my domain I see the page cannot be found. I don't know what can be wrong.

Pd: I have waited for more than 48 hours so changes should have propagated by now.

Comment: I see an `A` record for `rodrigoloza.com`, but nothing for `www.rodrigoloza.com`. Are you sure you set your `CNAME` up properly?

Comment: I followed the Heroku documentation. I only changed the CNAME in my domain manager, I did not edit the other records. I was also told that 'rodrigoloza.com.herokudns.com' is wrong and should be 'rodrigoloza.herokudns.com' but heroku asks for my full 'www.domain.com'.

Comment: Who told you that `rodrigoloza.com.herokudns.com` was wrong? There's a good chance it's right. `rodrigoloza.herokudns.com` is unlikely to work. And what subdomain did you use for your CNAME record?

Comment: The people from GoDaddy. After researching a bit I realize he is wrong. For my subdomain I used www. I have also tried to link my herokuapp domain but the same thing happens ... I think it might be heroku's problem.

Comment: This video might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=31s